# Getting shortest distances between features on separate polygon layers using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance

I have a county-level map for the state of North Carolina, U.S.

I would like to compute the shortest distance of each county to any point along the border of Georgia.

How would this be done?

I have looked all over this site and the internet for suggestions and cannot find much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [ArcGIS Resource Center](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001q000000.htm):

> Both input features and near features can be point, multipoint, line,
>   or polygon.

So you should be able to use the [Near Tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001q000000.htm) for both polygon layers as Rayner suggested but without needing to convert them. The Near tool can be found in the Proximity toolset of the Analysis tools in ArcToolbox.

[image]

Just set the Counties layer as the input feature and the Georgia layer  as the near feature. The following attributes would then be added to the Counties layer:

> - NEAR_FID—Stores the feature ID of the nearest feature.
> - NEAR_DIST—Stores the distance from the input feature to the nearest feature. The value of this field is in the linear unit of the input's
>     coordinate system.

I take it the NEAR_DIST values are what you need?

---

**Extracting the Georgia boundaries from the states shape file**

As for your data, you can extract the Georgia boundary from the states shapefile. Go to your states shapefile's attribute table and select Georgia.

[image]

The Georgia state should be highlighted. You can then extract it by right-clicking the states layer name in the table of contents and clicking **Data > Export Data**. This displays the Export Data dialog box. You can then export just the Georgia boundary by choosing the **Selected features** option from the dropdown menu.

[image]

You can then use the resulting Georgia layer as the Near Feature.