# Calculate distance between polygons on two separate layers using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, distance

For my purposes, I need to find for each polygon in one feature dataset (red polygons) the outemost (from edge to edge) polygon in the second feature datasets (green polygons). Paradoxically, seeking the opposite function of the [Near](http://desktop.arcgis.c) function in ArcGIS.

How would this be done?

[image]om/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm

Comment: When you say feature dataset I think you must mean feature class. In any event can you perhaps simplify your example so that you can make the polygon you seek clearer, please?

Comment: try https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35164/getting-shortest-distances-between-features-on-separate-polygon-layers-using-arc?rq=1

Comment: Create 3 different distance rasters from greens. Zonal statistics by reds into 3 different columns. Find max of these three. What type of statistics it's up to you

Comment: I apologize if my request has not been previously formulated correctly. 
Simply, I need for each red polygon determine which of the four green polygons is for him farthest.

Note that the boundaries of the this two polygon feature classes do not overlap.

Comment: This is exactly what I am talking about. Consider one red which has 3 distances 200,300,100. It means farthest is green number two. Period

Comment: If you have 4 greens replace all 3s by 4s in my comments